# costmap_2d requires macros.h header to build

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On a fresh checkout of diamondback-full on Lucid, I was unable to get costmap_2d to build. It kept complaining of not finding ROS_DEPRECATED and ROS_INLINE_FORCE. I was able to overcome this problem by including macros.h in every src/*.cpp file.

Is there a better way of getting a build? What am I doing wrong?

Update after Eric's comment: I followed the instructions here:http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu. Generally I go to my desired packages and do a rosmake && make. My std_msgs failed to build , citing "Header.h" was absent. I resolved the issue by manually copying msg_gen/include../Header.h to std_msgs/include. rosconsole had an unmet dependency of rostime, which I added in the manifest.xml and rebuilt.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10616/costmap_2d-requires-macros.h-header-to-build/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-23**:
What cpp files did you have to add the include to?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-17**:
Could you include the command you used to checkout diamondback-full and what commands you are using to build everything? Were there any errors building other parts of diamondback-full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

closing as self-answered

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0